# JButton and ActionListener causing many run-time errors

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, indexoutofboundsexception

So I am trying to make a version of Conway's Game of Life using Eclipse and JSwing, 
my issue is when I attempt to start the code to run a generation it instead produces a large amount of runtime errors The issue arises when I attempt to press the first JButton which I am currently using as a start button for the next generation of the simulation. The Cell class is just a set of setters and getters for both its current state and its place in the array of buttons, The list of errors that occur when I press the first button are below the code

```
public class MainPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JButton[] screen = new JButton[2500]; 
JButton start = new JButton("Start");
Cell[] cells = new Cell[2500];
int select = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    new MainPage();

}

public MainPage() {
    super("The Game Of Life");
    int k = 0;
    while (k < 2500) {
        screen[k] = new JButton("");
        screen[k].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cells[k] = new Cell(k);
        cells[k].setState(0);
        k++;
    }

    Container surface = this.getContentPane();
    surface.setLayout(new GridLayout(50,50));

    // k == row j == col
    for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {

           int finalI = i; // no final modifier
            surface.add(screen[i]);

            screen[i].addActionListener(e -> {


                Color color = screen[finalI].getBackground();
                if (color == Color.BLACK)
                {
                    screen[finalI].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    cells[finalI].setState(1);
                }
                else {
                    screen[finalI].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    cells[finalI].setState(0);
                }

            });
            screen[0].addActionListener(this);

    }

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);


}
public void setnewstates() {
    int k = 51;
    int screensize = 50;

    while (k < 2500 || k > 50 || k % 50 != 0 || (k + 1) % 50 != 0) // avoid borders for now
    {
        int neighbors = 0;
        int state = cells[k].getState();
        neighbors = cells[k - 1].getState() + neighbors; // check neighbors
        neighbors = cells[k + 1].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k + screensize].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k - screensize].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k + screensize + 1].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k + screensize - 1].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k - screensize - 1].getState() + neighbors;
        neighbors = cells[k - screensize + 1].getState() + neighbors;   

        if (state == 1) {
            if (neighbors < 2)
            {
                cells[k].setState(0);
                screen[k].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            if (neighbors > 3)
            {
                cells[k].setState(0);
                screen[k].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        else if (state == 0) {
            if (neighbors == 3)
            {
                cells[k].setState(1);
                screen[k].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    k++;
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == screen[0])
    {
        setnewstates();
    }
}
}
```

And Here are the errors that occur when I press the first button

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at MainPage.setnewstates(MainPage.java:72)
at MainPage.actionPerformed(MainPage.java:106)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"causing many run-time errors"* No, that's just one that passed through many code lines before it became obvious. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 0):

In `setnewstates()`, you start off by setting k=0, then one of the first things you do in the while loop is reference `cells[k - screensize - 1]`

eg:

```
int neighbors = 0;
int state = cells[k].getState();

if (k > 0) neighbors = cells[k - 1].getState() + neighbors; // check neighbors
if (k < 2500) neighbors = cells[k + 1].getState() + neighbors;
if (k + screensize < 2500) neighbors = cells[k + screensize].getState() + neighbors;
```

Just a thought : you're making your life really difficult by using a one-dimensional array.  Life is played on a 2-D grid (you have 50x50), so I'd recommend you experiment with a 2 dimensional array [50][50].

Comment: in order to get into that while loop k  has to be > 50 all of those requirements in the while loop is just so I don't have to deal with the edge of the box for right now so that isn't the issue

Comment: Ah my apologies .... but it'll be hitting the same kind of issue with `cells[k - screensize - 1]`  (eg when k=2);  I'll update my answer

Comment: Actually, those requirements in the while loops are ORed together, so it IS executed when k=0.